# gradle project sync fail after clone project from github

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I really need your help, I am facing this error when I'm trying to build github project :

[ERROR]: Unsupported method: GradleProject.getProjectDirectory()

and this is my build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and this is build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.pntutorial.pnrtcblog"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // TODO: Uncomment the following compilation lines
    compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
    compile 'me.kevingleason:pnwebrtc:1.0.6@aar'
}
```

and this is github project link

https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial

Comment: The project is really old. Try cloning this one https://github.com/smac89/android-webrtc-tutorial

Comment: @smac89 thank you this was helpful